# Altium PCB Layout

Tags: altium, layout

How can I make a single via or a hole with different sizes at different layers?

for example,
I have a 4 layer board and I Need 4mm hole size from layer 1 to layer 2 and 3.5mm size from layer 2 to layer 4.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: You might want to look at how buried vias are defined using layer drill pairs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that by placing two different vias on top of each other and adjusting the start and stop layer. Just be careful about how you're going to communicate this to your manufacturer.

NOTE: It looks wrong in 3D viewer, but the gerber data is correct.

[image]

Comment: thank you for your comment.
I have done it in same way but I had a doubt in 3D Viewer.
I Need it because I have to connect my board on top of another fixed board using screws and the screws are in such a way that it has two different Diameters.